# Explanations about FOLLOW function - Grammar

Tags: grammar, ll-grammar

I've some problems to understand the function FOLLOW. I cannot calcule follow functions of a grammar and that's not good. I tried exercises to understand this function and in particulary this exercise, I've this grammar :

S -> E

E -> T E'

E' -> + T E' | minus T E' |

T -> F T'

T' -> * F T' |

F -> id | ( F'

F' -> E ) | n )

Here the results of the calculating of follow function :

S     $

E          ), $

E'  ), $

T   +, minus, ), $

T'  +, minus, ), $

F   *, +, minus, ), $

F'  *, +, minus, ), $

I really don't understand why the FOLLOW(T)=FOLLOW(T') = { +, minus, ), $ } 
In the grammar that I give, theterminal symbols plus and minus never appears on the right of T or T' so if someon can explain me this, it will be cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually, FOLLOW(X) is the set of tokens that can come AFTER an X in a legal sentence in the grammar.  So to calculate it, you look at where X appears on the right side of a rule (any rule) and see what comes after it.  In the case of T', you have

```
T -> F T'
T' -> * F T'
```

since `T'` is the last thing on the rhs in both cases, you end up with FOLLOW(T') = FOLLOW(T) ∪ FOLLOW(T'), which is equivalent to FOLLOW(T') = FOLLOW(T).

For T you have:

```
E -> T E'
E' -> + T E'
```

which gives you FOLLOW(T) = FIRST(E') ∪ FOLLOW(E) ∪ FOLLOW(E') -- the FOLLOWs are included because E' expands to ε.  Depending on exactly whose formulation of FIRST and FOLLOW you use, that may mean that ε ∈ FIRST(E') (in which case you remove it from FOLLOW(T)) or that NULLABLE(E') = true, but the overall effect on FOLLOW(T) is the same -- it gets `+` and `minus` from FIRST(E') and `)` and `$` from FOLLOW(E)